# How to restore files from unusable Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My Ubuntu installation got messed up because of an upgrade (on archive manager - which is definitely my fault).

Every time I boot my laptop, after logging in, its background is blue with plain and silver panels. Too many errors shows up (it always says I don't have permission viewing its content).

I have so many important files there I'm wondering if its possible to remove the HDD and connect it in my Windows PC (to create copies).

Will it work, or will it just do what it does in my laptop? Or will it mess up my PC?

Answer (score 5):

It will most likely do the same if you install it in another PC.

I suggest you boot your laptop from an Ubuntu live CD and mount the messed up disk. Then you can copy your important files to another HD, via the network to your Windows PC, an USB stick or some storage on the internet (Ubuntu One, Dropbox ...)

After that you can try to recover your system or reinstall it, but make sure your important data is at a safe place first.

Here more info how to recover: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Answer (score 1):

Can you slave a linux HD in a Windows PC to retrieve files?
Yes, you can!

It is less time consuming to [boot live and copy stuff off](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) if you have an external HD.

There are things to be concerned with if you don't have an external HD and you **really** want to slave it in:

1. Do you know how to slave a disk?
2. Did you install with LVM?
3. Will you install the Ext driver for Windows?

If your answers are yes, no, and yes - then it's really simply put:

Install the [Ext2 filesystem driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) for Windows.
Slave the drive in with your laptop to IDE adapter
[image: adapter].
Boot your Windows installation.
Get your files off at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ruediger. Taking out the HDD won't really work that well and for a beginner to computer hardware (I am assuming you are via your question wording) it could cause problems.

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD (or USB, depending on which you have) and mount your HDD. Once you  do this, you should be able to access your data and save it to another USB disk.